# Let $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ be positive integers summing to $N$. What's an upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^k1/\sqrt{n_i}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality

**Disclaimer.** Sorry, I haven't looked into this one in any detail (as I should have). I was just thinking there out-of-be an elementary principle out here (pigeon-hole, Cauchy-Schwarz, Jensen, etc.). Which settles it in one line or so...

So, let $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ be positive integers summing to $N$.

## Question

> What's a good upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^k\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n_i}}$ in terms of $k$ and $N$?

## Generalization

Let $p_1,\ldots,p_k \ge 0$ with $\sum_{i}^k p_i = 1$.

> What's a good upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^k \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n_i}}p_i$ ?

---

## Edit

Ok, I just figured out I've asking the wrong question all along. I won't get very far trying to bound each term of an entangled sum individually...

So, here is the full business: Let $T$ and $k$ be positive integers. A each round $t=1,2,\ldots$, exactly one item from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, say $i_t$, is observed. Let $n_t(i)$ be the total number of times object was $i$ observed upto (and including) time $t$.

> **Question.** For a positive integer $T$, what is a good upper bound for $S_T := \sum_{t=1}^T\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n_t(i_t)}}$.

My rough guess is that this should be something like $C\sqrt{kT}$.

---

## Edit

Below, I solve the restated question (the first Edit).

By the pigeon-hole principle,

$$
\begin{split}
S_T:=\sum_{t=1}^Tf(n_t(i_t))&=\sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{i=1}^k 1_{\{i_t=i\}}f(n_t(i))=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{t=1}^T1_{\{i_t=i\}}f(n_t(i)) = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^{n_T(i)} f(n)
\end{split}
$$

**Case 1:** $f$ nonnegative and concave.

By Jensen's inequality, one has
$$
\begin{split}
S_T=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^{n_T(i)} f(n) \le kT\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^Tf(n)\frac{1}{kT} \le kTf(kT),
\end{split}
$$

**Case 2:** $f(x) := x^{-\alpha}$, $0 < \alpha \le 1$
It is an [elementary result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/132527/168758) that

> If $f(x)$ is a continuous positive decreasing function and $a_n =f(n)$ then 
>   $$  a_n + \int_1^n f(x)dx \le a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n \le a_1+\int_1^nf(x)dx.
> $$

Thus, if $f(x) = x^{-\alpha}$ with anti-derivative $g_\alpha(x) := (1-\alpha)^{-1}x^{1-\alpha}$ if $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $g_1(x):=\log(x)$, we can compute the above integral to get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{n_T(i)} f(n) \le 1 + g_\alpha(n_T(i))-g_\alpha(1).
$$

Now, using the theory of Lagrange multipliers, it's not hard to arrive at the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^kg_\alpha(n_T(i))$ is maximized when the $n_T(i)$ are equal for all $i$. Thus

$$
\begin{split}
S_T &= \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{n=1}^{n_T(i)} f(n) \le \underset{\sum_{i=1}^kn_T(i) = T}{\max}\;\sum_{i=1}^k (g_\alpha(n_T(i)+1-g_\alpha(1))\\
&\le \begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(k^\alpha T^{1-\alpha}+(\alpha-1)k)=\mathcal O(k^\alpha T^{1-\alpha}),&\mbox{ if }0 < \alpha < 1,\\ \log(T) + k=\mathcal O(\log(T)),&\mbox{ if }\alpha = 1.\end{cases}
\end{split}
$$

Thus if $f(n):=1/\sqrt{n}$ as in the original question, we get
$S_T \le 2\sqrt{kT}$ as claimed.

Comment: Sorry for the noise. I figured out I was asking the wrong question. Restated and solved in edited version.

Answer (score 1):

To maximize your sum you would want the denominators to be as small as possible; since each $n_k$ is a natural number we know that they are all at least $1$, and so the trivial upper bound of your sum is $k$.

I would wager that we can do better, though I am not really in a mood to try and prove this. What [compositions](https://math.mit.edu/~csikvari/composition_partition.pdf) of $N$ into $k$ parts are good candidates for maximization of this sum? Presumably it is the composition $(1,1,\ldots,N-k+1)$ and others resulting from permuting those entries around. This would give you an upper bound of $k-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N-k+1}}$, which should be tight.

For your generalization, we have a trivial upper bound of $1$, which follows by the same reasoning for the trivial upper bound above. A tight upper bound is probably going to be something like the following:
$$
1-\min\{p_{k}\}+\frac{\min\{p_k\}}{\sqrt{N-k+1}}
$$

If the trivial bounds are not good enough, then I would probably try and prove these tight bounds with some multidimensional optimization techniques; you have some function defined on fairly nice bounded region of $\mathbb{R}^k$, so something probably works nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I just obtained the same trivial bound at the moment. I was wondering whether one could  have something only involving $k$ and $N$ in products (e.g a product of a subset of $k$, $\sqrt{k}$, $N$, $\sqrt{N}$) ?

Comment: @dohmatob I doubt that a tight upper bound will have only $k$'s and $N$'s for the reason's I outlined in that second paragraph; consider the really simple example of $k=2$ and $N=10$. This is pretty clearly maximized by the composition $(1,9)$. My whole hypothesis is that as $k$ increases, even if $N$ is as small as possible, you are going to run into the exact same phenomenon where there are bigger gains in keeping many denominators small than trying to spread the love. Thus you are going to have something left over (namely that $N-k+1$), which kills any hope of using only your expressions.

Comment: @dohmatob For the case where $N=k$ (which is the smallest $N$ can be in this problem) your tight and trivial bounds will match, and then you get your wish of a bound involving only $k$.

Comment: The upper bound $k - 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N-k+1}}$ **is** tight because the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is strictly convex, any combination of $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ that maximize the expression can has at most one $n_i$ differs from $1$.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. Ok, just figured out I've been asking the wrong question all along. Post edited.

Comment: @dohmatob I'm a bit confused by your new formulation -- if this is some kind of random process then one or more of your $n_t(i)$ might be $0$, which makes the sum not well defined. I'm glad you have the argument you are looking for by your second edit, but I personally am not convinced you have a well stated problem let alone a good upper bound.

Comment: @dohmatob For instance, let $T=k=10$ and suppose in your $10$ rounds you draw each object exactly once. Assuming we get to drop terms that would otherwise be undefined, the sum you are interested in is $55$ and you propose to bound it with $10$, which is clearly not right.

Comment: @ItsJustCalculusBro You're right. That was a thinko. The sum of interested should be $\sum_{t=1}^T1/\sqrt{n_t(i_t)}$, where $i_t$ is the item observed on rount $t$. Fixed.